# How to replicate this option?

Tags: options, replication

I have a question I am not sure how to approach:
Suppose interest rates is 50%, a stock worth \$1 today can be worth \$2, \$1, \$0.5 next year.

If the option that pays \$1 only when S = \$2 is traded in the market and is worth \$0.125, calculate the price and replicating portfolio of the option that pays \$0.5 when S = \$1.

It has something to do with pay-off matrix but I don't know how to apply it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand well, you have a market with 3 states: up, flat or down.

You have 3 instruments:

1. The stock
2. The risk-free rate (50%)
3. The option

If you can create a portfolio today with these 3 instruments that can replicate de payoff of the option you have to price, then the **law of one price** tells you that the price of the option should be the price of this portfolio.

So, you have to solve a system of 3 equations with 3 unknown:

Assume you will hold $a$ stock, $b$ risk-free bond, $c$ option, and using fraction notation for 0.5, 1.5, the system is:

*Up State*: $a \cdot 2 + b \cdot \frac{3}{2} + c \cdot 1=0$

*Flat State*: $a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \frac{3}{2} + c \cdot 0=\frac{1}{2}$

*Down State*: $a \cdot \frac{1}{2} + b \cdot \frac{3}{2} + c \cdot 0=0$

From the third equation, you get $a=-3b$.

Substituting into the second, you get $-3b+\frac{3}{2}b = \frac{1}{2}$ which yield $b=-\frac{1}{3}$ and hence $a=-3 \cdot \left( - \frac{1}{3} \right)=1$.

Finally, substituting in the first equation, you get $1 \cdot 2 + \left( - \frac{1}{3} \right) \cdot  \frac{3}{2} + 1 \cdot c =0$.

This yields $c= - \frac{3}{2}$.

So the portfolio holding 1 stock, selling $\frac{1}{3}$ risk-free bond and selling $\frac{3}{2}$ options replicates perfectly the payoff of the option you have to price. The price of this option is hence $1 \cdot 1\$ - \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1\$ - \frac{3}{2} \cdot 0.125\$=0.48\$$

Comment: In the final sentence, you mean selling $\frac{3}{2}$ options and not $12$ right?

Comment: @Mat.S oh yes of course!